# Why does a Unit Test project need to install NuGet packages for classes it is testing

Tags: unit-testing, dll, reference

I have a project (ProjectA) that uses Microsoft.Graph and other things related to that package. I have another project (ProjectB) that Unit Tests methods in ProjectA. When I create an object from ProjectA in ProjectB then it complains that it could not load file or assembly which ProjectA references.

ProjectA constructor:

```
public GraphApi(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
{
    string[] scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential
    var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
    graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
}
```

ProjectB test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetGroups()
{
    GraphApi graphApi = new GraphApi(TenantId, ClientId, Secret);
}
```

Error that pops up from PojectA constructor, in line "var clientSecretCredential =...", when unit test runs:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Identity.Client, Version=4.57.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a613f4dd989e8ae' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

Microsoft.Identity.Client is referenced in ProjectA and has the same version as is mentioned in the error message, 4.57.0.0.

[image: Reference to Microsoft.Identity.Client version 4.57.0.0]

I am wondering if this is some sort of reference hell in ProjectA that is causing this instead of me needing to install the packages it complains about in ProjectB.

Why is this happening and how can I troubleshoot it?

P.S. I recently moved all of my projects from c drive to a new extra drive with the drive letter s. I am thinking maybe it has something to do with that since I seem to recall that this started around the time I moved the projects.